# Why is malloc returning null pointer when called inside a function?

Tags: c, stack, queue, malloc

I made a code in which `malloc()` is called, but it is returning a null pointer. When I call the same `malloc()` in `main()` and pass to the function, it is working totally fine. So please tell me what is the problem.

Here is my code. I am having problems with the `malloc()` in the function `reverse()`. The `malloc()`s in other functions are working fine. So why is there problem with the one in that function. I have enough memory in my computer, so that's definitely not the problem.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
typedef struct node
{
    int data;
    struct node *next;
} SNode;


typedef struct
{
    int count;
    SNode *top;
} Stack;

int isSEmpty(Stack *s)
{
    return (s->count==0);
}

void push(Stack *s, int x)
{
    SNode *temp = (SNode *)malloc(sizeof(SNode));
    temp->data = x;
    temp->next = s->top;
    s->top = temp;
    s->count++;
}

int pop(Stack *s)
{
    if (isSEmpty(s))
    {
        printf("Underflow");
        return -1;
    }
    SNode *temp = s->top;
    s->top = s->top->next;
    int t = temp->data;
    free(temp);
    s->count--;
    return t;
}
typedef struct qnode
{
    int data;
    struct qnode *next, *prev;
} QNode;

typedef struct
{
    QNode *front, *rear;
    int count;
} Queue;

int isQEmpty(Queue *q)
{
    return (q->count==0);
}

void enQueue(Queue *q, int x)
{
    QNode *temp = (QNode *)malloc(sizeof(QNode));
    temp->data = x;
    temp->prev=q->rear;
    temp->next = NULL;
    q->rear->next = temp;
    q->rear = temp;
    q->count++;
    if (q->count==1)
    {
        q->front = q->rear;
    }
}

int deQueue(Queue *q)
{
    if (isQEmpty(q))
    {
        printf("Underflow");
        return -1;
    }
    QNode *temp = q->front;
    q->front = q->front->next;
    int t = temp->data;
    free(temp);
    q->count--;
    return t;
}
void reverse(Queue *q)
{
    Stack *s = (Stack *)malloc(sizeof(Stack));
    s->count = 0;

    while (!isQEmpty(q))
    {
        push(s, deQueue(q));
    }
    while (!isSEmpty(s))
    {
        enQueue(q, pop(s));
    }
}

int main()
{
    char p = 'y';
    Queue *q = (Queue *)malloc(sizeof(Queue));

    q->count = 0;
    while (p =='y')
    {
        printf("Enter data to be Enqueued: ");
        int d;
        scanf("%d", &d);
        enQueue(q, d);
        printf("Do you want to enter more data? y/n:");
        scanf(" %c", &p);
    }
    printf("Original queue Front: %d Rear: %d\n", q->front->data, q->rear->data);
    reverse(q);
    printf("Reversed queue Front: %d Rear: %d", q->front->data, q->rear->data);
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: You have several `malloc`s here. Which one returns 0?

Comment: How do you know that `malloc` returns `NULL` if you are not checking it? In general `malloc` returns `NULL` if there is no more memory left.

Comment: Format your code properly, specially if you want/need others to read it.

Comment: @HolyBlackCat i specified in the question, the one in reverse function

Comment: @Pablo I removed the checking statement while posting the code as it is not part of main code.

Comment: Pardon, I didn't notice that. Then can you add the check back, so we can be sure that it's not somehow broken? Also, are you sure you don't call `malloc` an absurd amount of times before it returns `0`?

Comment: @IharobAlAsimi I  had it formatted. it got unformated after i copied and pasted it.

Comment: There is http://format.krzaq.cc (but I'm not sure how formatting could break when copying out of an IDE).

Comment: @HolyBlackCat that check is not a big thing. just used if(s==NULL) print some thing after the malloc. well i dont thing malloc is called absurd amount of times, just 2-3. and even then i have 8gb ram. it aint gonna get filled by allocating bytes

Comment: @Gameatro It's because you had tabs instead of spaces for indentation. And some other things are just the way you format it which is wrong (IMHO). Style is something that you can choose, but there are bad choices of course.

Comment: @Gameatro "that check is not a big thing" -- If your null-check is what is showing you that your code is failing, you need to include it in a [MCVE]. It happens often enough around here that someone is sure that they got a null-check right, but a stray comma or missing equals sign or some other thing causes the check to go haywire. Not saying that this was your problem, only saying that it is an important part of your program if that is how it was when it failed.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You aren't initializing all the fields of the `*q` struct that you initiallay allocate in `main():

```
Queue *q = (Queue *)malloc(sizeof(Queue));

q->count = 0;
```

Then you pass that `q` pointer to `enQueue()` and do things like:

```
q->rear->next = temp;
```

I think you may also use `q->front` without having initialized it.

These things are undefined behavior and in your case are probably corrupting the heap causing `malloc()` to not work as you expect.  If you're working on Linux valgrind might be useful.

Comment: no, the problem is in reverse function. i used some printfs and ifs a breakpoints, the malloc there is returing null pointer.

Comment: So what?  You just don't notice the problem until `reverse()` is called. The problem in `enQueue()` (and/or other similar problems) is setting up the problem in `reverse()`.

Comment: @Gameatro Listen to more experienced programmers, I am 100% sure the problem is exactly at `q->rear->next = temp`. I know it because I used a tool called [valgrind](http://valgrind.org) on your program and found it out.

Comment: but why is it causing problem in reverse function?

Comment: @Gameatro It's called Undefined Behavior. Google it.

Comment: k thnks for help

Answer (score 5):

Your program is hardly running out of memory, which is why `malloc()` would return `NULL`. Instead a combination of bad programming style and messy code, is causing problems related to access of uninitialized memory which is **undefined behavior**, once you trigger the UB you can't predict program's behavior anymore.

The first thing you need to fix, is avoiding this kind of construction

```
q->rear->next = temp;
```

because `q->rear` might be `NULL` and thus you would invoke UB if you dereference it.

Then you need to initialize the members of the struct explicitly, `malloc()` only *allocates* memory for you to use, it does no initialization whatsoever, a good method to do it would be to create a function that allocates and initializes empty instances, like the following

```
Queue *queue_new(int count) 
{
    Queue *queue;
    queue = malloc(sizeof(*queue));
    if (queue == NULL)
        return NULL;
    queue->count = count;
    queue->front = NULL;
    queue->rear = NULL;
    return queue;
}
```

Also, don't mix declarations with code. I had to search for the definition of `Queue` to write the above function, and I did so with the find/replace feature of my code editor.

Place all structure and type definitions together above all the code, to make it easy to find any one of them.

Comment: Or you could use `calloc` instead which set the allocated memory to 0, great for initialization of structures with pointers.

Comment: @Pablo If you want to set every member to `0` yes, but in my example you could create something like `queue_new(4);` in which case using `calloc()` would only avoid the need to explicitly setting `front` and `rear` to `NULL`. I generally avoid `calloc()` unless I REALLY want to initialize to `0`.